# Not able to parse JSON in php with numeric key

Tags: php, json

This is my code which is giving error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '24' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\block_gecko\front\index.php on line 186

```
echo '<td style="font-size: 120%;">' .$character->24hour . '</td>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP variable cannot starts with a numeric character. Try this:

```
$var = '24hour' ;
echo '<td style="font-size: 120%;">' .$character->$var . '</td>';
```

Example :

```
$json = json_decode('{"24hour":"test"}');
$key = "24hour";
echo $json->$key; // "test"
```

Or convert your JSON [as array](https://php.net/json_decode) (`json_decode($data, true)`) and use :

```
echo '<td style="font-size: 120%;">' .$character['24hour'] . '</td>';
```

Another way (Thanks @mickmackusa) :

```
$json = json_decode('{"24hour":"test"}');
var_dump($json->{'24hour'});
```

Comment: @mickmackusa Oh! Sorry, didn't take care about that.

Comment: No worries.  Just know that there was a third option to solve this.  Wrap in `{}`.

Comment: @mickmackusa Right! I always forget this one. Thank you!

Comment: it is not a duplicate question i have checked that question but didnt find the answer like this :/

Comment: @blockGecko It's also works. Check the last way of the updated answer.

Comment: @syscall yup that also works :P my mistake :P

Comment: @blockGecko you're welcome :)